# Rails3 routes is this the best way?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

There are a number of other Rails2 -> 3 routing questions but mine is less complex and is actually not giving me an error. So why the question? Well I want to make sure I am not using additional unnecessary code. Disclaimer: I am new to Ruby/Rails learning Rails3 via Simply Rails 2 book trying to adapt/figure out all the errors in hopes of getting a more in-depth understanding of the language.

So I have my first view, index.html.erb (in app/views/stories). When I initially went to view it at localhost:3000/stories like the book said I got an error `No route matches "/stories"` after changing the url to localhost:3000/stories/index the page showed up perfectly.

A look at the routes.rb shows:

```
Shovell::Application.routes.draw do
  get "stories/index"
```

I have now created a second view which is new.html.erb (in app/views/stories):

```
<% form_for @story do |f| %>
<p>
  name:<br />
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
</p>
<p>
  link:<br />
  <%= f.text_field :link %>
</p>
<p>
  <%= submit_tag %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

This view wouldn't show up at any URL I tried. Looking at the server log I decided it was a routes thing. I changed the routes.rb to this:

```
Shovell::Application.routes.draw do
  get "stories/index"
  get "stories/new"
```

Now when I go to localhost:3000/stories/new the page works fine (albeit the method error that is part of the exercise in the book).

It doesn't seem right that I would have to manually enter every view into routes.rb, there must be a way to set root and let it recognize all the files there. Can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

```
root :to => "stories#index" # This means you render the root url by using stories controller and index action

resources :stories # The standard way to generate a resource (with index, new, edit, show, create, update, destroy actions automatically defined for you and supports some customization)
```

So for your case, actually the `resources :stories` gave you the urls you need.

Comment: Thanks so much, I did read through that edge guide previously and I think at one point I had something like `root => stories/index` which was kinda on the right track but obviously not right. Everything is working well now!